# How to get current user's permission levels (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, permissions, item-level-permissions

I need to get approve , edit and read permissions for a site .How can i find this?

Answer (score 1):

Use EffectiveBasePermissions to get permissions of the user. Example:

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/Web/effectiveBasePermissions"
```

In any case the end result is **high and low permission masks** use SP.BasePermissions().has as can be seen in below example:

```
function checkPermissions() {
return jQuery.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/Web/effectiveBasePermissions",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    }
});

checkPermissions.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var managePerms = new SP.BasePermissions();
    managePerms.initPropertiesFromJson(data.d.EffectiveBasePermissions);

    var manageLists = managePerms.has(SP.PermissionKind.manageLists);
    var manageGroup = managePerms.has(SP.PermissionKind.createGroups);
    var manageWeb = managePerms.has(SP.PermissionKind.manageWeb);
    alert("Manage Lists: " + manageLists);
    alert("Manage Group: " + manageGroup);
    alert("Manage Web: " + manageWeb);        
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ajax call with URL format as `https://yoursite/_api/web/roleassignments/getbyprincipalid(userid)/roledefinitionbindings`